# Property Let procedure issue

Tags: excel, vba, oop, properties

I am having trouble getting a property let procedure to work in VBA.

Here is my code pared down as far as possible to illustrate the issue.

```
Option Explicit

Dim IDX As String

Public Property Let Blaby(IDX As String)
    IDX = Blaby
End Property

Public Property Get Blaby() As String
    Blaby = IDX
End Property



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Blaby = setting
    MsgBox Me.Blaby
End Sub
```

When I run this and click the command button, I get a blank msgbox. If I hard code a value for the property in the let procedure, the message box displays that value, so I am pretty sure something must be wrong with my Let statement. Can anyone figure out what it is? I am at my wits end so it is probably something obvious.

Comment: You are using the same variable name for the module-level `IDX` and the parameter `IDX` in `Public Property Let Blaby(IDX As String)`, try changing it to something else and the assignment of the module-level variable should be to the parameter so e.g. `Public Property Let Blaby(argIDX As String): IDX = argIDX: End Property`

Comment: Or use `Me.IDX = Blaby` instead.

Comment: @Raymond Wu Thanks! Made your modification and it worked the first time. I was misunderstanding how property let/get is supposed to work but I think I have a solid grasp now.